# How to change jquery parameter with a submit form?

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie at jQuery. I was trying some things but I need some help.

I have the following script

```
jQuery(function($){
        $("#query").whatever({
          parameter1: 32,
          parameter2: 4,
          query: "something"
        });
      });
```

I need a script to change `query: "something"` to `query: "something else"` by a submit form. Is it possible?

ps: i change `$("#query").something` to `$("#query").whatever` to dont confused with the parameter `query: "something"`

Actualy i use jquery code from http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/ I want to change the "query" parameter in example 2 as i told before, by a submit form.

Comment: please post your codes if possible. Also please elaborate the requirement. Its not so much clear, as off where will this code be present? will the form be in the same page?

Comment: The fact that you are calling `.something()` and passing it an object containing parameters or options tells me that you're using a plugin or an AJAX call. Different plugins allow you to change options in different ways. Please give us a real example of the code that you're using; right now your question is to vague for us to give you any real help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

with a form :

```
    <form>
        <input name="newvalue" id="newvalue" type="text"/>
        <input type="button" id="onclickUpdate" value="update" name="update"/>
    </form>
    <script>
        var obj = {
            parameter1 : 32,
            parameter2 : 4,
            query : "something"
        };
        $(function() {
            $('#onclickUpdate').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('old : ' + obj.query);
                $.extend(obj, {
                    query : $('#newvalue').val()
                });
                console.log('new : ' + obj.query);
                $("#query").something(obj);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Why use `extend`? Why not just use `obj.query = $("#newvalue").val()`?

Comment: Actualy i use jquery code from [link](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/) I want to change the "query" parameter in example 2 as i told you, by a submit form.

Comment: By the way the above script dosent seems to work. The default parameter dosent change with the new one.

Comment: sorry, typed from instead of form and used button instead of input. check again. I prefer using extend because you can override multiple properties at once and you don't need the target object to be consistent (if you override obj.query.a and obj.query is null you will throw an error)

Comment: Did you check the [original code](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/) (Example No2  click at code) that i want to make changes?

Answer (score 0):

Well, suppose you are using $.ajax() to submit the form. While submitting the form, you might pass 3 to 4 keys as well as their values as data, right? In one of these key-pair values, you want a default value, so instead of building a hash from scratch, start with the default one, add to it the other ones you want to send:

```
initdata = {query:"something-else"}; //not needed if you don't include the "query" key while populating tobesent
tobesent = {}; //may be through serializing a form through serializeArray or something
tobesent = $.extend(tobesent,initdata);  
$.ajax({
url : "foo.php",
data: tobesent,success: function() {}
});
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, enclose the options as a dictionary, and preset the **query** key with the value **something else**, and pass the options dictionary as the parameter to be passed.

Comment: I've been working with jQuery for a long time yet I have a hard time to get what you are saying...... and you expect a "newbie" to understand this?

Comment: Ummm, the concept of dictionary has nothing to do with jQuery, does it, it comes with vanilla Javascript, so I thought any "newbie" in JQuery should be comfortable with the idea of something from good old Javascript. How come it is so difficult to understand?

Comment: And by the way, your solution does the same thing, only it uses the jQuery function **extend()** to do the same thing.

Comment: you answer to his question with 1 phrase only. If you want to answer explain more